# How to link a field of a model to another models's field in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to link first_name and last_name field of my extended user model to the base User of Django so that changing the values of the fields in one model also affects the values in the other model. I have extended the Base User Model to store additional information about the user and I need to enable the users to edit all those values along with first_name and last_name with a single form.

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = "Linked to first_name of base User Model"
    last_name = "Linked to last_name of base User Model"
    other fields....
```

Comment: What you are looking for is class inheritance. This is not the correct way to go about this. You need to do "class Account(User)" in other words subclass the User model and then the fields + other additional fields will automatically be integrated in your model.

Comment: Why not keep those values in the user model and only add your custom fields in the `Account` model?

Comment: Subclassing the User model is not that easy in Django. Read https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

The article is a bit outdated so you have to be careful with some of the lines, but the logic is still relevant.